# Closure counter with 'classic' function doesn't work, but with IIFE it does. Why?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have two counter realizations seems identical (for me), here is my code:

```js
var fakeCounter = function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        return i++;
    }
};

// And

var counter = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        return i++;
    }
}());

// And here the confusion:

console.log(fakeCounter()()); // 0
console.log(fakeCounter()()); // 0
console.log(fakeCounter()()); // 0

console.log(counter()); // 0
console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
```

So, the first counter doesn't work, while the second does. And I can't get why, because `counter()` is equal to `fakeCounter()()` on my mind.
Can someone clarify that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are both, correct and wrong, at the same time: `fakeCounter()()` and `counter()` are the same, *but only when invoked once*:

- How they are alike:

  - `fakeCounter()` creates a function with a closure, as does the IIFE for the `var counter`.
  - The next `()` invokes that function.
- How they are different:

  - `fakeCounter()` creates a *new* function every time, that captures its own `var i` inside it.
  - The IIFE is only invoked once, so there exists *only one* `var i`.

I encourage you to play around with this bit of code:

```
let a = fakeCounter();   // a is a counter
let b = fakeCounter();   // as is b
// ... but are they the same? Hmmmm...
console.log(a === b);   // false  -- Nope, they are separate functions

console.log(a());         // 0
console.log(a());         // 1
console.log(a());         // 2

console.log(b());         // 0
console.log(b());         // 1
console.log(b());         // 2

console.log(counter());   // 0
console.log(counter());   // 1
console.log(counter());   // 2
```